# How to supply RequestContext data to the constructor of a domain object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-structures, oop

I need data from the `RequestContext` to be available when the constructor executes on one of my Domain objects. The following example is what I'm already doing.

```
public Site(IDataUniverseService dataUniverse, IRegionService regionService)
{
    this.DataUniverse = dataUniverse.GetDataUniverse(this.Id);
    this.Region = regionService.GetRegion(this.Id, /* this value comes as a URL parameter */);
}
```

This is fine because StructureMap can easily supply the services because they come from the domain.

But how can I get it to also supply an interface to the `RequestContext`? Or should I be doing this differently?

This is kind of what I have in mind:

```
public Site(IDataUniverseService dataUniverse
    , IRegionService regionService
    , IRequestContext context)
{
    var region = context.RouteData.Values["region"].ToString()

    this.DataUniverse = dataUniverse.GetDataUniverse(this.Id);
    this.Region = regionService.GetRegion(this.Id, region);
}
```

but ideally, the `IRequestContext` would just have that value readily available as a property, rather than the `RouteData.Values["region"].ToString()`

Answer (score 4):

Add parameters corresponding to what values you need from RequestContext so the caller can extract the necessary data and send only that.  Your domain objects shouldn't deal with the request context directly.